OIDC with Keycloak and Yarp inside Docker
I am trying to setup an authentication gateway with Yarp and Keycloak. Both are running locally inside docker containers. The problem is that the OIDC-Url in the browser always contains the internal keycloak address:
// Yarp-Settings (settings.keycloak.json)
"OpenIdConnect": {
  "Authority": "http://keycloak:8080/realms/master", // docker internal address
  "ClientId": "gateway",
  "ClientSecret": "*******************",
  "Scopes": "openid profile email offline_access"
},
[...]

As you can see i am using the internal keycloak address for the authority because otherwise yarp can not establish a connection.
Now when i try to access something over my gateway, i always get redirected to http://keycloak:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=gateway&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F...... 
Of course it is not reachable because it is a docker internal address.
I tried out changing some keycloak settings like HOSTNAME_URL or FRONTEND_URL, but i still get the wrong Url (should be http://keycloak:7777/realms/master/...)
My docker compose:
services:
  gateway:
    build: .
    container_name: gateway
    environment:
      - GATEWAY_CONFIG=conf/settings.keycloak.json
      - Logging__Console__FormatterName=Simple
    volumes:
      - ./conf:/app/conf
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:25.0.2
    container_name: keycloak
    environment:
      KC_FEATURES: admin-fine-grained-authz,token-exchange
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_URL_DATABASE: keycloak
      KC_DB_SCHEMA: public
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://keycloak_db/keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: root
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: root    
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    command: ['start-dev']
    ports:
      - '7777:8080'
  
  [...]

Btw when i host keycloak on a separated machine (Authority: "http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:7777/realms/master") everything works (makes sense because there is only one address then).
Any help is appreciated, thank you :)
